Tracing the maximum and minimum when the curve $f'(x)$ is given

My approach is as follow
In the closed interval $x\in[0,2]$ the function increases and reaches maximum value at $x=2$ and then decreases and reached some minimum value at $x=4$
Definitely $f(2)>[f(0),f(4)]$ but among $f(0)$ and$f(4)$  which is least how do we check it

Notice that the area under the curve between 0 and 2 is larger than the area between 2 and 4, so
$$
 f(4) - f(0) = \int_0^4 f'(x)dx = \int_0^2 f'(x)dx + \int_2^4 f'(x)dx > 0
$$
Therefore, we must have $f(0) < f(4) $

Thành Nguyễn‘s answer is pretty comprehensive, but I also wanted to add an intuitive explanation based off of their answer.
Since the area under $f’(x)$ at $[0,2]$ is greater than the area under the curve at $[2,4]$, we can infer that the change in $f(x)$ at $[0,2]$ is greater than the change in $f(x)$ at $[2,4]$. And since the area at $[0,2]$ is positive while the area at $[2,4]$ is negative, we know that the amount of increase from $f(0)$ to $f(2)$ is greater than the amount of decrease from $f(2)$ to $f(4)$. If you visualize this, you can see how $f(0)$ is the lowest point, $f(2)$ is the highest point, and $f(4)$ is in between.
